# What's the difference betweeen httpclientandroidlib and apachehttp library in android?

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

On decompiling a popular app's .apk, generally I encounter httpclientandroidlib as a package in those apps. I wonder what difference is between httpclientandroidlib and apachehttp? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [website of httpclientandroidlib](http://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) explains:

> This is a repackaging of HttpClient 4.1 for Android. The version of HttpClient in the Android SDK is 4.0beta2. There have been several updates to HttpClient and some much-needed bugfixes like auth caching since the 4.0beta.